# Incorrect value returned using redis PUBSUB NUMSUB when using ReactiveRedisMessageListenerContainer

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

I'm using `Spring Data Redis` and Redis Pub/Sub capabilities. I recently started using `ReactiveRedisMessageListenerContainer` to be able to multiplex the same connection for several subscriptions.

I was also relying on using PUBSUB NUMSUB command to get how many users were subscribed to a specific channel, but after starting using `ReactiveRedisMessageListenerContainer`, that stopped working properly.

From what I understand from the documentation, the same connection can be used for multiple subscriptions and this leads me to assume that using PUBSUB NUMSUB would get me the correct number of subscription to a channel, even if the connection is multiplexed.

This is what I use to create the `ReactiveRedisMessageListenerContainer`:

```
@Component
class RedisConfiguration(
    private val factory: ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory,
) {

    @Bean
    fun reactiveRedisMessageListenerContainer(): ReactiveRedisMessageListenerContainer {
        return ReactiveRedisMessageListenerContainer(factory)
    }
}
```

And then I use it like this to make the subscription:

```
   fun subscribe(vararg channelNames: String): Flux<out ReactiveSubscription.Message<String, String>> {
        return container
            .receive(*buildChannel(*channelNames))
            .doOnSubscribe {
                // some code in here
            }
            .onErrorResume { error ->
                // some other code in here
            }
    }
```

Is there anything that I might be missing that may be causing this problem or is it normal that the subscription count is not correct when using `ReactiveRedisMessageListenerContainer`?